# XSLT table cells depends on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

```
<xsl:for-each select="A">
<tr>            

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@a='True'">
<td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="../@e"/></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="../@b"/></td>
<td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@be"/></td>
<xsl:for-each select="T">
<td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="@o"/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="../@e"/></td>
<td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="../@b"/></td>
<td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@be"/></td>
<xsl:for-each select="T">
<td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@o"/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</tr>
```

This part of my xslt makes the rows of a table.

The columns are ../@e, ../@b, @be, @o

For each A element, I create a row at the table.

The cells of the **3rd column** have **white background color** no matter what.

So:
First of all the first 2 columns are not full and **ONLY the first cell of the first TWO COLUMNS have to be full**. All the other cells of them are empty.

**BUT** if there is at least one @i attribute in any A element that is True, the cells of the first 2 columns (1ST ROW) have to be yellow to indicate that there is a @i that's True.

Please help me to figure it out. It has turned into a nightmare the last few days.
Thank you in advance.

The full XSLT transformation is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<!-- param values may be changed during the XSL Transformation -->
<xsl:param name="shared_item_name"> Animal </xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="description"> Birth </xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="properties"> Kind </xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>Problem</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="AA">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$shared_item_name" /> </th>
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$description" /> </th>
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$properties" /> </th>
        <xsl:for-each select="IRO[position()=1]/P[position()=1]/T">
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="@s" /> </th>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>               

<xsl:for-each select="AI">

    <xsl:for-each select="A">

        <tr>

        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="../@e"/></td>
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="../@b"/></td>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </xsl:if>

        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@be"/></td>

        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@a='True'">
        <xsl:for-each select="T">
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="@o"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="T">
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@o"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        </tr>

    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="AI">
    <xsl:for-each select="A">

        <tr>            

        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@i='True'">
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="../@e"/></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="../@b"/></td>
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@be"/></td>
        <xsl:for-each select="T">
        <td bgcolor="#FFFF00"><xsl:value-of select="@o"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="../@e"/></td>
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="../@b"/></td>
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@be"/></td>
        <xsl:for-each select="T">
        <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select="@o"/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>

</table>
</xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you insert the XML source for your transformation, and the full XSLT?

Comment: @YvesB I inserted it. Hope for your advice :\ I'm lost!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need also to provide the expected HTML, since your explanations are not easy to understand.

Comment: @YvesB is that ok?
http://www.flickr.com/photos/blondie_lg/7548763740/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: OMG MR. @YvesB THANK SOOOO MUCH!!!!!! I have no words for expressing my happiness right now! Thank you -> 00 :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt, but your request lacks some precision.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<xsl:param name="shared_item_name"> Shared Item Name </xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="description"> Description </xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="properties"> Properties </xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>Problem</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="IR">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$shared_item_name" /> </th>
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$description" /> </th>
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$properties" /> </th>
        <xsl:for-each select="IRO[1]/P[1]/T">
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="@s" /> </th>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>               
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="P">
    <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test='count(preceding-sibling::P)=0'>
                <xsl:variable name='c'>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test='(@i="True") or (count(following-sibling::P[@i="True"]) &gt; 0)'>#FFFF00</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>#999999</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <td><xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'><xsl:value-of select='$c' /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select='../@n' /></td>
                <td><xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'><xsl:value-of select='$c' /></xsl:attribute></td>
                <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select='@dn' /></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select='@dn' /></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="T">
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test='../@i="True"'>#FFFF00</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>#999999</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select='@v' />
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Mr. @YvesB I know that I'm asking too much, but if you have the time and the willingness I'd like you to help me further.

Your answer was exactly what I asked for. But the real problem that I have, has more requirements. One of them is that:

-if there is at least one i=True at a IRO/ P element AND at least one at IRO/ IRO/ P element then the color of the ../@n is RED

-if there is at least one i=True at a IRO/ P element AND NOT at any IRO/ IRO/ P element then the color of the ../@n is YELLOW

Comment: -if there is NOT i=True at a IRO/ P element but there is at least one i=True at any IRO/ IRO/ P element then the color of the ../@n is ORANGE

-if there is NOT i=True at a IRO/ P element and NOT at a IRO/ IRO/ P element then the color of the ../@n is GREY

I tried to do it with the descendant attribute but I fail :(

Comment: Would you have an input XML that has the different conditions, so that we can see if an updated XSLT works?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Now I have to study hard and understand every single detail of it! You're amazingly kind Mr. @YvesB :)))
IT WORKS PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 0):

With the additional reqts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<xsl:param name="shared_item_name"> Shared Item Name </xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="description"> Description </xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="properties"> Properties </xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>Problem</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="IR">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$shared_item_name" /> </th>
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$description" /> </th>
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="$properties" /> </th>
        <xsl:for-each select="IRO[1]/P[1]/T">
            <th> <xsl:value-of select="@s" /> </th>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>               
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/IR/IRO/P">
    <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test='count(preceding-sibling::P)=0'>
                <xsl:variable name='c'>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test='(@i="True") or (count(following-sibling::P[@i="True"]) &gt; 0)'>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test='count(../descendant::P[@i="True"]) &gt; 0'>#ff0000</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>#FFFF00</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test='count(../descendant::P[@i="True"]) &gt; 0'>#FF6600</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>#999999</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <td><xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'><xsl:value-of select='$c' /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select='../@n' /></td>
                <td><xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'><xsl:value-of select='$c' /></xsl:attribute></td>
                <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select='@dn' /></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select='@dn' /></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="/IR/IRO/IRO/P">
    <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test='count(preceding-sibling::P)=0'>
                <xsl:variable name='c'>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test='(@i="True") or (count(following-sibling::P[@i="True"]) &gt; 0)'>#FFFF00</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>#999999</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <td><xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'><xsl:value-of select='$c' /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select='../@n' /></td>
                <td><xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'><xsl:value-of select='$c' /></xsl:attribute></td>
                <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select='@dn' /></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="#999999"><xsl:value-of select='@dn' /></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="T">
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name='bgcolor'>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test='../@i="True"'>#FFFF00</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>#999999</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select='@v' />
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case the templates for the 2 levels of P elements have to be distinguished